# how to replace object inside array of array swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have **array of array** i want to replace object of it. I have one key value so i can **compare** with all objects and if match found then replace whole object in that particular array. My code is written in swift.

i have key "name"  if that match with object then replace whole object.

For example, **"name":"javed"** compare with all objects (myproject.ObjChat.name) if match found then replace with new ObjChat.

```
(

    (

    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat"
),
    (
    "myproject.ObjChat"
),
    (
    "myproject.ObjChat"
),
    (
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat",
    "myproject.ObjChat"
)
)
```

Comment: if you need constantly replace some values in your array of arrays your maybe need a dictionary of arrays, for performance improvements, or even a dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: i am using iterative for loop for comparision but not getting and also performace issue

Comment: let finalArray = array.map{$0.map{if$0.name == "javed" { // my changes }}}

Comment: if you keep a dictionary of dictionaries [key:[key:value]] you can improve performance a lot as I think